# Check duplicate editText before writing into .csv

Tags: android, database, csv

I have several editText in my FirstActivity for CSV:

```
Button save;
CSV csv;
StringBuffer filePathc;

public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.mapcard.MESSAGE";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_card);

txtName= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
txtCompany= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtCompany);
txtPhone= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPhone);
txtMobile = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtMobile);
txtAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtAddress);
txtEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
txtWebsite = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtWebsite);
txtTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);

filePathc = new StringBuffer();
filePathc.append("/sdcard/Android/data/");
file = new File(filePathc+filename.toString());
csv = new CSV(file);

save=(Button)findViewById(R.id.save);
save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override   
public void onClick(View v) {

csv.writeHeader(txtName.getText().toString()+ "," 
                        +txtCompany.getText().toString()
                        + "," +txtPhone.getText().toString()
                        + "," +txtMobile.getText().toString()
                        + "," +txtAddress.getText().toString()
                        + "," +txtEmail.getText().toString()
                        + "," +txtWebsite.getText().toString()
                        + "," +txtTitle.getText().toString());

Intent intent = new Intent(NewCard.this, Template.class);

intent.putExtra("name", Name);
intent.putExtra("company", Company);
intent.putExtra("phone", Phone);        
intent.putExtra("mobile", Mobile);
intent.putExtra("address", Address);
intent.putExtra("email", Email);
intent.putExtra("website", Website);
intent.putExtra("title", Title);

startActivity(intent);
```

SecondActivity is to write this data into .csv file:

```
public class CSV {
private PrintWriter csvWriter;    
private File file;

public CSV(File file) {
this.file = file;
}

public void writeHeader(String data) {

try {
    if (data != null) {

        csvWriter = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file, true));
        csvWriter.print("\r\n"+",");
        csvWriter.print(data);
        csvWriter.close();

    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}}
```

File in directory is successfully created and data is inserted. I am trying to check the data like Name or Email, if it is duplicate/already recorded to not save into .csv and warn user with Toast "same data".

I think it is something to do with line:

```
try {
    if (data != null) {
```

Your helps and suggestions are appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following function

```
public boolean exist(String newData){
   try {
        FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(file);
        BufferedReader myReader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(fIn));
        String aDataRow = "";
        String aBuffer = "";
        while ((aDataRow = myReader.readLine()) != null) {
            if(aDataRow.contains(newData))//<--check if data exists
               return true;
        }
        txtData.setText(aBuffer);
        myReader.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    return false;
}
```

And change your write header function to:

```
public void writeHeader(String data) {

try {
    if (data != null&&!data.isEmpty()&&!exist(data)) {

        csvWriter = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file, true));
        csvWriter.print("\r\n"+",");
        csvWriter.print(data);
        csvWriter.close();

    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Comment: thx @vipulmittal write header is done but first part is having some clashing in my code. how better i can nested it?

Comment: what is the problem in first part??

Comment: Illegal modifier for the variable exist; only final is permitted

Comment: where are you using exist method it should be CSV class

Comment: i nested in CSV class. error: The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type CSV. over: EditText txtName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtName);

Comment: you are already doing it in FirstActivity  why do you need to get txtName in CSV. Also CSV is not an activity you cannot call find view by ID. Post your current code.

Answer (score 1):

`data != null` doesnt cover the case that the String is just empty, but not null. So basically you get `""` from the textview by calling `getText()`. adding `&& !"".equals(data)` should fix that problem

**UPDATE**

Well, there is a difference between an empty, and an uninitalized String. An uninitalized String means you declared it like `String a;` but nothing further.

If you use editText.getText() the editText will return a String which has been initialized but contains only what is currently in it. So basically if there is nothing in the editext it will return "".

And to sum this up:

```
String a;
null == "" // false
a == null // true
"".equals(editText.getTExt()) // true if the editext doesnt contain anything
```

Comment: @Umitk added some examples, if hope you get what i mean

Comment: But this will check for the data in hand. What i want is to check in csv from the Names inserted earlier. Lets say, there might be 20 over data and none of them should be duplicated.

Comment: so check every line for the key associated with the data, in your case the name i suppose